# Cryptographic way to detect deleted rows in a database table

Tags: cryptography, databases, integrity

I have a web application talking to a PostgreSQL database.

My threat model is the following:

Attacks must not occur at rest. What i'm afraid of is **unwanted deletion of data on a specific table**, let's call it the `data` table.

What i mean by "*unwanted deletion*" is deletion of rows inside the `data` table that would not be done from the web app.

In this threat model, we only trust the web app. Not the database or any other external system (except if it can provide integrity guarantee).

I thought about having a secret key on the application side, compute an HMAC of the full `data` table and verify it everytime i insert a new row, and then update the HMAC with the new inserted row.

Here is an overview of the whole process:

1. The web app has a secret key for computing HMACs.
2. The database holds the current HMAC for the `data` table.
3. When inserting a row (this is the moment when we want to check for
   unwanted deletions), we select every rows from `data` and we compute
   HMAC of all the rows.
4. If the HMAC is the same as the one inside the database, then no rows
   were altered.
5. The web app inserts the new row and compute the new HMAC, then
   update the HMAC in the database.

This seems to be very costly because i have to read the entire table and perform two HMACs computations on the whole data (one for computing the original HMAC, one for computing new HMAC).

This system could also work with digital signatures.

One problem is that an attacker could still rollback the `data` table to previous state and updating the database with an old HMAC. How could i deal with that ?

The main question is, how could i check with cryptographic guarantee that no unwanted deletions happened in the `data` table everytime i insert a row ?

Thank you.

Comment: "no rows were deleted when inserting a new one." What does that mean? Except if there are triggers or "ON CONFLICT" statements, no rows can be deleted when just inserting one. I don't think you are looking at the problem at the correct side, adding cryptography won't help it seems more a DB design to review.

Comment: what i meant by that is that no malicious user which has control over the database must be able to delete rows without being detected on the application side.

Comment: Where do you plan to store the verification data?

Comment: the HMAC would be store within the database i guess.

Comment: What you want is not possible. See the 10 laws of security: https://www.marshall.edu/it/departments/information-security/10-immutable-laws-of-security/

Comment: i have updated the question to tell a bit more about the threat model. Also i raised one more issue about the verification process i'm thinking about.

Comment: "what i meant by that is that no malicious user which has control over the database must be able to delete rows without being detected on the application side." Databases have a concept of "row security" and you can create users with different roles and permissions. Your problem has to be solved at that level instead of trying to tack on top of it a magic silver bullet that you call cryptography.  See for example https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Comment: Well, i'm not trying to tack a "magic silver bullet". What is good about cryptography is that even when the system gets fully hacked, still the attacker might not be able to compromise the data's integrity, confidentiality or authenticity. Thank you for the documentation, but i already know how to manage postgresql privileges and users. It's not really what i'm looking for unfortunetaly...

Comment: For freshness, Merkle Tree, for row protection, use HMAC of the rows in a column. Merkle tree has O(log n)-time for delete and updates. This assumed the application server cannot be breached.

Comment: Very interesting. Freshness means guarantee that the data is not an older version ?

Comment: freshness and rollback two terms. One can guarantee the freshness so that there is no rollback.